# Floating and element to the right at the bottom of footer

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue adding some social icons to the footer on a wordpress theme I am making. The problem is that I cannot get the icons to float the the bottom right corner of the footer.

Here is what I am trying to acheive: The grey elements are existing, and the red element is the social icon strip, where I want to add it to.

[image]

The only way I can achieve this is to manually add a margin that is the full width like this:

```
.social-icons {
    padding: 0!important;
    margin-left:864px;
    list-style-type: none!important;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;

}
```

The problem with this is that when the window is resized the social icons are all over the place. I know float right would work great but the problem is that it doesn't.

If I try this:

```
.social-icons {
        padding: 0!important;
        list-style-type: none!important;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        float:right;
}
```

**It ends up like this:**

[image]

The element titled logo already uses float:right; so that may have something to do with it. Here is the logo div:

```
.footerlogo img {

    float: right;

}
```

The thing is if I take the float:right; off the logo div and keep the float:right; on the social icon strip, the social icon strip will now be in logos position, with logo moved back. As such:

[image]

Can anyone guide me in the direction of sticking the social icons(red element in image) into the bottom right corner and let me know how I can accomplish this, since the normal way of using float right wont allow it to float to the bottom right, only to the logos position.

Comment: can u show me link of your website and show full code

Comment: `float:left` and `float:right` makes always makes some problem why don't you use `clearfix` hack http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `right` property to 0, that should make the element align to the right edge of the closest positioned parent:

```
.social-icons {
    padding: 0!important;
    list-style-type: none!important;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works to get the icons in the bottom right corner, but when I resize the browser it ends up moving the icons back and forth. Also the outermost icon on the right doesn't line up with the right edge of the logo above it. Other than that it is the only solution here that is working(somewhat).

Comment: @user1632018 Can you provide us with a reproducible example of your issue in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hi Koala, thanks in advance for the help. [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWeZF/2/). Since It is a wordpress theme that uses the theme customizer I had to make some changes to remove the wp settings strings and re add the html manually.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have an extra classes/subclasses for the header nav, for some reason it was using that one in the jsfiddle instead of the footer nav class so the logo and nav menu were opposite. Here is a js fiddle without the nav classes removed. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWeZF/3/)..Thanks a million :)

Comment: @user1632018 would this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/XWeZF/7/show/? Not to be rude but you have kind of a mess there with the fixed widths and the floating

Comment: I couldn't seem to get it to work. When I put that into my footer code it arranged everything but the menu to the outside of the pages instead of lining up with the menu. So technically it worked, but the fixed width was part of my themes design. I know it was something you kind of needed to see the theme to understand. The JSfiddle didnt do it any justice. Sorry for the late reply, I was trying to fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try out putting .social-icons in a div say parent and make parent div float right;
float property never works with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Give the Footer main div to `position:relative`

and give social icon div to `position:absolute` and give value for left and top