# For each pixel smaller or larger browser is, add/remove 1px from divs right element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to do this. I figure the easiest way is probably going to be javascript. I have a social icon container that is very stubborn. you can see my previous question here: [Floating and element to the right at the bottom of footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287333/floating-and-element-to-the-right-at-the-bottom-of-footer) I want it in the bottom/right of my footer, lined up vertically with a logo in the top/right of my footer. I found the best way to get it where I want is when the social icons container is like this:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:80px;
```

Now the problem with this is when the browser is resized the icons move in too far. I was thinking I could use some javascript to continuously check the browser size and for each pixel the browser moves in, it automatically decreases 1 px from the `right` attribute of the social container. I could also go with the left attribute, and do the opposite.

Can this be done, and if so how could I go about doing it?

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle with your footer code?

Comment: Consider [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead. It doesn't sound like you need to resize it for every single pixel but only when the screen gets small enough.

Comment: @Murshid Sure no problem. I actually made one in my previous question that I posted the URL to as an example. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XWeZF/2/

Comment: Here is the updated JS fiddle with the right px's added. http://jsfiddle.net/XWeZF/8/

Comment: I agree with @Kirill . Media queries are the best option. But I come up with another fix meanwhile! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something relative to how wide the screen is, rather than if the screen is getting smaller or larger.  If you want it to be 80px from the right at 800px width then 70px to the right at 700px, you could do something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( window ).resize(function() { 
        $('div').css("right", $(window).width() / 10 ); 
    });
});
```